# FormatException was unhandled by user code datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

When I try to get a date value from a textbox the value is:  `"05/22/2014"`
I want to insert it into my database field that has a datetime format so I would like to convert it first.  So I am using the `Convert.ToDateTime` function on the value from the text property of the text box.  But I am getting an error saying

> `FormatException` was unhandled by user code.  String was not
>   recognized as a valid DateTime.

Isn't that what I'm doing when I use `Convert.ToDateTime` on the textbox text value?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="cldStartProj" CssClass="datePicker" TextMode="DateTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
DateTime dtDateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(cldStartProj.Text);
```

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: And what format do you expect the user to use? Will they always use the same format? Are you enforcing that?

Comment: Hi Soner, I don't know the answer to that question, how would I find that out?

Comment: Hi Jon, I believe the DB default is:  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mi

Comment: @user255817 Just check the value of your CultureInfo.CurrentCulture propery. Write in your program, debug and see

Comment: Thank you for the tip Soner ... the property was 'en-ca'  ~thank you

Answer (score 1):

[`Convert.ToDateTime(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default. Here how its [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs#fce604498e2f810b);

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(String value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return new DateTime(0);
    return DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Probably, your `CurrentCulture` doesn't have `MM/dd/yyyy` format as a standart date and time. That's why your `Convert.ToDateTime` will fail. You can see all standart date and time patters with [`GetAllDateTimePatterns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getalldatetimepatterns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Here an example on [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net);

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns().Dump();
```

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods parsing your custom date and time strings.

```
string s =  "05/22/2014";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
   // parsing successful
}
else
{
   // not successful
}
```

But rememer, [`/ Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning in custom date and format strings. It means like *replace me with the current culture date separator*. That means even if you have exact same format with your string, if your [`DateSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `/`, your parsing operation will fail.

> the property was 'en-ca'

As I said, your culture doesn't have a standart format as `MM/dd/yyyy`. Here a full list of standart formats that your `en-ca` culture support;

```
foreach(var format in CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-ca").DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns())
{
    Console.WriteLine(format);
}
```

Output will be;

```
dd/MM/yyyy
dd/MM/yy
d/M/yy
yyyy-MM-dd
yy-MM-dd
M/dd/yy
dd-MMM-yy
dd-MMM-yyyy
MMMM-dd-yy
MMMM d, yyyy
d-MMM-yy
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
MMMM-dd-yy h:mm tt
MMMM-dd-yy hh:mm tt
MMMM-dd-yy HH:mm
MMMM-dd-yy H:mm
MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt
MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm tt
MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm
MMMM d, yyyy H:mm
d-MMM-yy h:mm tt
d-MMM-yy hh:mm tt
d-MMM-yy HH:mm
d-MMM-yy H:mm
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm
MMMM-dd-yy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM-dd-yy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss
MMMM-dd-yy H:mm:ss
MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM d, yyyy H:mm:ss
d-MMM-yy h:mm:ss tt
d-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt
d-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss
d-MMM-yy H:mm:ss
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss
dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt
dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
dd/MM/yyyy H:mm
dd/MM/yy h:mm tt
dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt
dd/MM/yy HH:mm
dd/MM/yy H:mm
d/M/yy h:mm tt
d/M/yy hh:mm tt
d/M/yy HH:mm
d/M/yy H:mm
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm
yy-MM-dd h:mm tt
yy-MM-dd hh:mm tt
yy-MM-dd HH:mm
yy-MM-dd H:mm
M/dd/yy h:mm tt
M/dd/yy hh:mm tt
M/dd/yy HH:mm
M/dd/yy H:mm
dd-MMM-yy h:mm tt
dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt
dd-MMM-yy HH:mm
dd-MMM-yy H:mm
dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm tt
dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt
dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm
dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm
dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss
dd/MM/yy h:mm:ss tt
dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt
dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss
dd/MM/yy H:mm:ss
d/M/yy h:mm:ss tt
d/M/yy hh:mm:ss tt
d/M/yy HH:mm:ss
d/M/yy H:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss
yy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt
yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt
yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
yy-MM-dd H:mm:ss
M/dd/yy h:mm:ss tt
M/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt
M/dd/yy HH:mm:ss
M/dd/yy H:mm:ss
dd-MMM-yy h:mm:ss tt
dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt
dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss
dd-MMM-yy H:mm:ss
dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss
MMMM dd
MMMM dd
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
h:mm tt
hh:mm tt
HH:mm
H:mm
h:mm:ss tt
hh:mm:ss tt
HH:mm:ss
H:mm:ss
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
MMMM-dd-yy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM-dd-yy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss
MMMM-dd-yy H:mm:ss
MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM d, yyyy H:mm:ss
d-MMM-yy h:mm:ss tt
d-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt
d-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss
d-MMM-yy H:mm:ss
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss
MMMM, yyyy
MMMM, yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("05/22/2014",
                    <your expected format>,
                    Cultureinfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Hi @Neel, what can you give me an example of how I would write the argument your expected format?  Would it be "yyyy-mm-dd" ?

Comment: it can be your wish it might be "MM/dd/yyyy" always remember MM must be upercase

Comment: Be careful about `/` format specifier. It has a special meaning in custom date and time format. I explained it in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is the code that worked best for me, thank you to all for you responses.

```
 private String FormatDate(String _Date)
        {
            DateTime Dt = DateTime.Now;
            IFormatProvider mFomatter = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            Dt = DateTime.Parse(_Date, mFomatter);
            return Dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
```

Comment: Although this works, it's not the best way of going about it. Please try to implement the other answers, your code will be much cleaner and you'll have a better understanding of how to parse strings to DateTime and format them back to strings.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion mason, I did try the other solutions but kept getting errors, probably due to the way I was implementing them, I will go back and try again.

Comment: This might work as you said but this is not a good way. For example, if OP has a format that `CultureInfo("en-US")` doesn't have, your `DateTime.Parse` throws exception.